# Google DFP SetTargeting resulting in blank ads

Tags: google-dfp

When I add a "Set Targeting" code to the end of an ad line on the website, the ads are going blank. Note that these ads have been running just fine before I added the targeting code.

Here's what my code looks like before the set targeting code:

```
googletag.defineSlot('/XXXXXXXX/My_Desktop_Header', [[970, 250], [970, 66], [728, 90], [970, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-4').addService(googletag.pubads());
```

Here's what my code looks like with the set targeting code:

```
googletag.defineSlot('/XXXXXXXX/My_Desktop_Header', [[970, 250], [970, 66], [728, 90], [970, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-4').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting("group","ten").setTargeting("author","john");
```

If I remove the setTargeting portion, the ads come back immediately.

Also worth noting that I added the key-value pairs in the Inventory section of DFP - group/ten and author/john

Answer (score 2):

From my experience I find it best to chain the setTargeting before the addService like so:

```
googletag.defineSlot('/XXXXXXXX/My_Desktop_Header', [[970, 250], [970, 66], [728, 90], [970, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-4').setTargeting("group","ten").setTargeting("author","john").addService(googletag.pubads());
```

Alternatively you could set it as Page Level targeting unless you require specific targeting on a per ad unit basis.

```
googletag.pubads().setTargeting("group","ten");
googletag.pubads().setTargeting("author","john");
```